# pos_tag fails on text in ALL CAPS

Tags: nltk

I am working with text which is, unfortunately, given in ALL CAPS. The default `nltk.pos_tag` function does not do a very good job on this text (it thinks everything is a proper noun).

What is the best way to deal with this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best would be to apply [truecasing](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=truecasing) to your text before POS-tagging.

If that is too much efford for you, you can transform your Python string `x` to lower characters using `x.lower()`, that should at least avoid the problem of getting only proper noun tags (there might be some confusions with too less proper noun tags though).

You could train a POS-Tagger by transforming a tagged corpus previously to `lower` aswell, but if you want to get the best results you probably want to go for the truecasing.

Comment: Training a new tagger on a corpus converted to lower case worked a little better, but still didn't give me the results I wanted. What seemed to work in the end (I haven't rigorously tested this) was training a tagger that tagged words as either lowercase, capitalized, or uppercase.